# Kubernetes the good practice for load balancing from outside

Tags: kubernetes

I am creating a Kubernetes Cluster and I installed Prometheus Kube metrics state on it.
I have LoadBalancers outside of the K8s cluster with HAProxy.

I am wondering on what is the best practice to loadbalance this service who is running in only one node. I thought to expose it with NodePort, and LoadBalance it from the HAProxy server checking before forwarding the request which node is currently running the service.

I'm not sure that's the best thing to do in this case.

Someone experimented can help on it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NodePort` services are exposed on all nodes even if they run only on one of them. The only difference is that one extra hop is added whenever the service is not running on the same node haproxy sends requests to.

So the way you described should work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, is that how you would have done it?

Comment: Mostly yes, except I'm using cloud load balancers instead of haproxy.